# In TNG S04E11 "Data's Day", how/why does Data serve as "father of the bride"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

During and before Chief O'Brien and Keiko's wedding, Data is both referred to as, and performs the traditional duties of, father of the bride. I'm not aware of it being commonplace in our timeline for a mere friend of the bride to serve in this role - is it perhaps because:

- Keiko's father, Hiro, was dead (he doesn't appear to be), or
- Keiko's parents were simply unable to attend the wedding, or
- It has become a purely ceremonial role, which any male close to the bride can fill

Or something else altogether?

Answer (score 14):

**You're partially correct**: Keiko's father, Hiro, was unable to attend the wedding as it was in deep space and as Data introduced Keiko & Miles he was asked to share this special day with them.

Data, not being what you might call *best friends* with either, still had a huge part in both of their lives by bringing them together. As standing at their side was out, for the aforementioned not BFFs, as was officiating which is the Captain's duty. All that was left would be walking the bride to the altar or "giving away the bride."

*Giving away the bride* is an antiquated tradition from the days when women were their father's property until they got married and became their husband's property. Today parents or families instead give their blessings in traditional and non-traditional ways where the bride may be walked down the aisle, sometimes by both parents or by a close relative.

Since that is the case today it is not hard to understand Keiko's request to Data would represents her life on the Enterprise prior to starting a family with Chief O'Brien.  Data, her analytical confidant of whom she closely associates with her next step in life, would be the best of the choices at hand if she feels she would like to carry on that tradition.

Comment: How do you know that her father was in deep space?

Comment: I do know that the tradition in its original form is antiquated, but I'd never encountered anyone other than a parent or relative do it in our time, hence my curiosity. Good answer, thanks.

Richard, I believe Hikaru is referring to the wedding itself being in deep space, as it was.

Comment: @Richard -k0nane's correct, I was referring to the wedding being in deep space. Near the Romulan Neutral Zone, from what I recall.

Comment: @HikaruIchijyo - Without any references, I've yet to be convinced that this is anything more than your own opinion.

Comment: @Hikaru - Good answer, it's exactly what I understood from watching the episode but you laid it out for us rather well.

Comment: @k0nane - Serendipitously I encountered a literary reference to a situation where someone other than a parent, or relative , might 'give the bride away'...  As I've just gotten to the bit in David Copperfield where he marries Dora Spenlow.  The marital plans Dickens lays out explains that Mr. Dick will be walking the bride to the alter.  I point it out as it gives some precedent for Data's part in the marriage in that Mr. Dick is not related to Dora and in fact he might not even be related to David.

Comment: @ Hikaru & Co. - I have one for you: Chloe asked Clark to give her away when she was getting married in Smallville Season 8 (which I am watching right now, don't judge me... I know it's not a very good show but I've made it this far).

Comment: "antiquated" "today" This answer is heavily biased towards whatever your particular culture is, Hikaru!

Comment: "standing at their side was out, for the aforementioned not BFFs" - somehow, one would assume such rigid traditional rules would have further faded away in a future society like the federation, also given the high degree of cultural mingling of different traditions that must have happened by then. Even on nowadays' Earth, weddings are far more varied than always following fixed plans such as "best friends invariably stand next to the bridal couple".